# Creating two arrays from list comprehension

Tags: coffeescript, list-comprehension

Right now, I am doing this in CoffeeScript:

```
keys = (key for key of data)
values = (v for k,v of data)
```

Where `data` is an an object (not an array). I am trying to create two arrays, where keys is an array of the property names and values is an array of the values.

This compiles to:

```js
var keys, values;
keys = (function() {
    var _results;
    _results = [];
    for (key in data) {
      _results.push(key);
    }
    return _results;
  })();
  values = (function() {
    var _results;
    _results = [];
    for (k in data) {
      v = data[k];
      _results.push(v);
    }
    return _results;
  })();
```

I'd like to be able to combine these two loops into a single loop, and can't figure out how (or if it's possible) to do this using a list comprehension.

A different attempt I made was to create two arrays and push the items to them myself:

```
keys = []
values = []
keys.push k for k,v of data
```

This lets me push the key just fine, but I can't figure out the syntax to push to `values` as well.

How can I create two arrays from a single list comprehension? Am I better off writing the loop myself?

Comment: Depending on your environment, you can also get the keys using `Object.keys(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest would be to loop yourself:

```
keys = []
values = []
for key, value of data
   keys.push key
   values.push value
```

which transpiles as

```
var key, keys, value, values;

keys = [];

values = [];

for (key in data) {
  value = data[key];
  keys.push(key);
  values.push(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[@Jimmy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11417185/581845) is probably the simplest if you are not using external libraries, but if by any chance you are already using Underscore, you can generate an array of `[key, value]` arrays and then [`zip`](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) them together:

```
[keys, values] = _.zip ([k, v] for k, v of data)...
```

The usage of splats is the same as doing `_.zip.apply(_, [k, v] for k, v of data)`.